# there is a bot code on you tube

Tags: solidity, metamask, contract-design, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bot

there is a bot code on you tube, where can i go to check if its a scam> here is the code.

code:

`https://codepastes.com/raw/wJLpHt`

you tube:

`https://youtu.be/a2oGKFSWhuk?si=gJiqVdatk17qXi2f`

Comment: any code from YouTube is not for production. they can only be used for educational purposes. you need to have the knowledge to write secure code or else hire someone.